# Look up ip addresses of multiple hosts with same name

Tags: dns

Is there any way to look up the ip addresses of all hosts with the same host name?

The reason I want to do this is that at work I prefer to use an ethernet connection with my laptop whenever possible but some times I must take it with me to other parts of the building and use wireless. The ethernet and wireless connections are assigned separate ip addresses that both point to my laptop's host name. When I plug my computer back into the ethernet port after it was connected to wireless, `dig hostname` continues to return the wireless ip address for several hours (even though the wireless connection has been disabled). If I do a reverse look up with `dig +short -x ipaddress`, both the old wireless and the new wired `ipaddress` return the same host name. So it seems like the name server is aware that my ethernet connection is associated with my host name. Ideally, the name server would update right away, but I don't have control over that. I would settle for being able to figure out my host name by cycling through all addresses associated with a hostname if I could find a way to get more than the first address associated with a particular host name.

Comment: It sounds like it's using dynamic DNS update to change the address of the hostname when you switch from wired to wireless connection. So there's only one DNS entry at a time. The reason it takes a while for the change to take effect is because of caching.

Comment: What Barmar said. But `dig` (without `+short`) will tell you what the TTL is (or more accurately, how long until it expires) in the second column of the record's entry. It depends on the how your dynamic DNS was implemented, but it's possible there may be nothing you can do until that record expires. If your machines are on the same subnet, you can use [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) through [Avahi](http://avahi.org/).